# fixing lead boot on waste vent

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

The lead boot around the waste vent has worn away. I have no idea how it happened, but I need to fix it. I was thinking of just buying another boot, cutting the bottom off, cutting the top of the existing boot off, and sliding the new boot over the old one.

I that a good way to fix it? If so, should I affix the new bolt to the old one somehow? If not, what is a better way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the photo you posted I can see you have a different problem from what you may think. The reason the vent pipe is damaged is because a "critter" has ben gnawing it away!

The most likely suspects in the animal world (in N.A.) would be in the rodent species: squirrel, rat, chipmunks, porcupines to name just a few. You can see the small serration grooves cut by their continually growing front and lower teeth.

What is extremely astounding is that the material is lead. A soft metal! You have a very determined and serious critter wanting 'in' to your house! Normally I would suggest en-circling the pipe with a wire mesh, but I would think it could rip through it and come back for seconds!

Repair or replace the vent as easiest and best you can. To stop the chewing apply a coating of roof patch to the pipe, covering it completely. I would try to catch the pest to prevent it from future damage elsewhere and from infiltrating your home.